# Run a method for a certain amount of time

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

So I have a method that is suppose to make an an object move up rapidly. The code inside is :

```
b2Vec2 force;
force.Set(_body->GetLinearVelocity().x, _body->GetLinearVelocity().y+1.0f);

for (b2Body* b = _game.world->GetBodyList(); b; b = b->GetNext())
{
    if (b->GetUserData() == character)
    {
        b->SetLinearVelocity(force);
    }
}
```

The code is not important, I want to know how I can stop this process after a few seconds or once it reaches a certain `y` point. because atm it runs out of the screen!

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Just test if the y position of the body is below the threshold you don't want it to cross:

```
for (b2Body* b = _game.world->GetBodyList(); b; b = b->GetNext())
{
    if (b->GetUserData() == character && b->GetPosition().y < 300)
    {
        b->SetLinearVelocity(force);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, I actually did that, but the effect doesnt seem as realistic as I want it to be. any idea how to shoot things into the screen realistically like fruit ninja does? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create an nstimer for periodically calling the selector which has your code and put it in repeat mode.
this will go on forever.. so in order to stop it after a particular amount of time put this entire thing in a new method and call that method inside a new nstimer.

so basically a timer inside a timer.